# XCode: Best Way To Handle A New View In A Tabbed Application

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In an iOS Tabbed Application I'm making, I've got tabs to load different viewControllers, which is pretty standard. What I'd like to do is make a few buttons (with images on them) load up another view with the button image maximized to the screen. However, I'm not really sure how to go about doing this. I don't want a new tab for this, I just want another view to show the full image, and then a button to return to the tabbed view. I've experimented a bit with making a subview to do this, and I've attempted to change the main viewport to the new view, with no success. If someone could point me in the right direction, and maybe give me a solid concept as a jumping-off point, I would really appreciate it.

And to clarify, I'm not looking for "the best way", per se. I'd be willing to accept a quick and dirty fix. But if you know of more than one way to handle this situation, I would appreciate whichever one you personally think is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it by creating a UINavigationController to use as the primary tab view. When you want to show the full screen button, you create a new UIViewController subclass (below) and push it. That class will return YES for the method "hidesBottomBar" (its something like that).

This new view controller will be a traditional controller. You can create a UIImageView to fill the view (or you can probably replace the view with the imageView). In the viewDidLoad you'll set the UIImage of the view (or you can enter its name in the nib).

When someone clicks on the button, then you'll pop that view and return to your tabbed view (where the tab bar is showing).

I did something like this (not a big button), so I know the tab bar can be made to hide on the push. You can also hide the navigation bar so it never is even show (again, not 100% sure at the moment how to do it but its possible).

Comment: Actually, a follow-up question: How would I change the window from inside one of my subView classes? For example, if I've got a Tabbed Application, with an instance of a class inside a tab, how can I call from that instance of the class to change views? I don't know how to modify the window, or how to access a UINavigationController from an instance of a View class inside the UINavigationController. I'm sorry if this is a basic question, or if I'm going all over the place here. I'm pretty new to Objective C, and I'm kinda flying by the seat of my pants programming in it.

Comment: What I do to allows communication is to add public properties to the appDelegate (and I make that a global too, but this is of course offensive to some). In any case you can always get to your appDelegate (through the UIApplication object). So by including the interface for the appDelegate in any class, you can ask it to navigate you to somewhere (using a method you wrote of course). So I have a few objects that are exposed this way, and it more easily lets me switch tabs etc. This is all code you write.